# VirtualAllocEx fails GetError returns ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am trying to create a process with CreateProcessA in Suspended mode and then allocating memory on base 0x400000 address, Problem is when i set dynamicbase flag on, virtualallocex fails randomly, but when i turn off the dynamicbase flag it fails everytime.

```
VirtualAllocEx(PI.hProcess, ImageBase,SizeOfImage, 0x3000, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
```

I want to allocate memory at a specific Address i.e at ImageBase, which i am not able to do, after creating a process is suspended state.

I want to load code at that address and execute it after process resumes.
Thank You

Comment: Something already loaded at that address?

Comment: nope, i have created new process, and even if it is there, it should not fail randomly?

Comment: Have you turned off address layout randomisation?

Comment: dynamicbase flag off means aslr off right?

Comment: Always fails when dynamic base is off and randomly when on strongly suggests that something is already loaded there and that is why your allocation fails.

Comment: Creating a process in suspended mode does not prevent the system from loading modules into the newly created process object. Obviously, the memory you are trying to allocate is already taken by modules loaded into the process. The fact that it reproducibly fails, when dynamic base is off, and occasionally, when its on is a strong indication that this is the case.

Comment: @AlokSaini I presume you're trying to create a no-integrity process. If that's the case I would suggest looking at the [chromium sandbox code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/sandbox/win/src/) as that's sadly a non-trivial endeavor right now.

Comment: @Anders ok if something is loaded there, then how i can free it?

Comment: @IInspectable - before process begin execute - only *ntdll.dll* and *exe* itself mapped into process address space. all another dlls loaded only after process begin run (resume).

Comment: @RbMm: Yes. I suppose that's pretty much the gist of my previous comment, no?

Comment: @AlokSaini - *if something is loaded there, then how i can free it* -`ZwUnmapViewOfSection`

Comment: @RbMm source? I'm pretty sure any non-delay loaded dependencies are loaded by the loader when the executable is loaded.

Comment: @Mgetz: No, they are not. Processes in Windows are self-initializing. The bootstrapper in ntdll.dll does all that. Once the process resumes/starts execution. (Source: [Why do I get ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE from GetModuleFileNameEx when I know the process handle is valid?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150716-00/?p=45131)).

Comment: @Mgetz - this is very well known fact - how process startup. kernel load only *exe* and *ntdll.dll* to the new created process. when first thread begin executed in process - *ntdll.dll* already begin load static import by *exe*

Comment: @RbMm ok let me try that

Comment: ok,is the question that dumb to receive neg reputation?

Comment: The question is somewhat unclear. It doesn't explain, what you expect. Or why.

Comment: sure, then i think it should be edited, not discouraged.

Comment: You are the only one that can conceivably edit the question, so as to not turn it into a different question, that is in conflict with your intent. You have access to the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49320182/edit) link just like everyone else. So go ahead, and edit the question.

Comment: That edit does not answer the questions I asked: What do you expect, and why do you expect that to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to allocate some memory in the process then you should let `VirtualAllocEx` pick a free address for you by specifying NULL as the base.

If you want to modify something in the process then you must use toolhelp/PSAPI functions to find the real module base address and use `VirtualProtectEx` to change the protection of the pages you wish to modify before calling `WriteProcessMemory`. You also need to call `FlushInstructionCache` if you changed code in the process.

You can use `VirtualQueryEx` to find information about those pages, `VirtualAllocEx` probably fails because a module is already loaded there.

Comment: i want to allocat memory on a specific address as i am tryin to load a dll in memory, i dont want to handle relocations

Comment: also as per your comment, i freed up the memory at that address and of size i want with virtualfreeex, virtualallocex still fails

Comment: If another module loaded there then you can't just free it. What does `VirtualQueryEx` say about those pages?

Comment: @AlokSaini - *i dont want to handle relocations* - in this case you need find more advancing way to inject/load dll from memory or not do this at all. your address range already occupied :)

Comment: @Anders what info is relevant? AllocationProtect Gives PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY, Protect gives PAGE_READONLY, state gives MEM_COMMIT

Comment: What about the type? MEM_IMAGE means a .exe/.dll is loaded there.